# Creating a custom "WHERE" filter in Excel SQL connection

Tags: sql, excel, select

I have easily created a custom SQL Query to populate an Excel from an SQL database.
This was quite straightforward and easy (Data/from External sources/Microsoft SQL - and then edited the command text section of the connection properties)

But now, I would like to use a WHERE clause with a parameter from a cell.

From what I read on every tutorials and similar SO questions, I should simply have to use a question mark and Excel will understand it and allow me to define a cell.

**Sources:**

[How to add parameters to an external data query in Excel which can't be displayed graphically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091908/how-to-add-parameters-to-an-external-data-query-in-excel-which-cant-be-displaye)

That's what I did:

[image]

Unfortunately I got this dialog telling me that some info are missing:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Microsoft Query first , and then change the Command Text later.

Refer from this： [Excel: Send multiple values in "Command text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346563/excel-send-multiple-values-in-command-text)

Comment: Indeed, I used the SQL connection and not the microsoft Query